# How to bind local context block to global context in Rebol2?

Tags: bind, rebol, scoping, rebol2

As I understand it, you are supposed to be able to bind any block to any context.  In particular you can bind a global context block to a local context:

```
>> a: context [
    print: does [rebol/words/print "yeah!"]
    f: func[b] [do bind b 'print]
]

>> a/f [print "hello"]
yeah!
== "hello"
```

So it must be possible to bind a local context block to the global context too?  But my attempts were unsuccessful:

```
>> b: context [
    b: [print "hello"]
    print: does [rebol/words/print "yeah!"]
    f: func[] [do bind b 'system]
]

>> b/b
== [print "hello"]

>> do b/b
yeah!
== "hello"

>> b/f
hello

>> do b/b
hello
```

It seems I made it but:

```
>> equal? bind? 'system bind? in b 'b
== false

>> same? bind? in b 'f bind? in b 'b
== true
```

What is my error here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are binding the words in the block assigned to `b/b`, you aren't binding the word `b` itself.

```
>> equal? bind? 'system bind? in b 'b
== false
```

This compares two objects, the first is the one that `'system` is bound to, and the second is the one that `in b 'b` is bound to (the top-level `b` object).

The thing is that blocks aren't really bound, the *words in the block* are bound. The blocks themselves don't have any bindings, not even as a concept. Also, the block that is assigned to `b/b` is just a value that happens to be assigned to `b/b`, it's not the word `'b`.

This comparison should work:

```
>> equal? bind? 'system bind? first get in b 'b
== true
```

What you are comparing with this is the binding of the first word in the block assigned to `b/b`, which is that `print` that you bound earlier. That word is what you changed the binding of in `b/f`.

Answer (score 4):

The binding information is carried by words, not blocks. When a block is rebound, the binding process will affect the words contained in the block. So your `b/b` block (and not the `in b 'b` word) has been rebound correctly, but your check is wrong. You need to retrieve the context from one of the rebound words inside the block, as in:

```
>> equal? bind? 'system bind? b/b/1
== true
```